# Нагрузка сервера с авторизацией

Tags: яндекс-танк

Требуется проверить работу нескольких приложений, но предварительно требуется пройти авторизацию. Лента с патронами выглядит следующим образом:

- GET (cookie)
- POST (cookie)
- GET

Для авторизации, пока, берём одного пользователя, но было желание брать его из внешнего файла или базы (полагаю, нужно перечитать TANK API).
Как я понимаю требуется ammo type requests, но постоянно получаю множество ошибок, а инструкция не отвечает на поставленные вопросы.

```
/admin/login

238
[User-Agent: Yandex-tank]
[Connection: close]
[Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate]
POST /admin/login
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=TiWu%2BOVx%2FQ53QSha9ecFv31bfncvPndp0b1gT7zKuHJeS7sndEyyN%2B3Pp6EzXp4PwTQyeSu3guDgCIAAx%2FIhwg%3D%3D&admin_user%5Bemail%5D=XXX@XXX\r\n
```

Вопрос в том как правильно составить патроны для последовательности GET/POST и работать с куки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить cookie мы обычно заранее ходим за авторизацией в сервис, полученную куку кладем в патроны в заголовок Cookie. Это можно сделать с помощью `curl` или посмотреть в браузере в консоли разработичка.

Если стреляете фантомом -- танк сам авторизоваться не сможет
т.к. нельзя последующий запрос сгенерить на основании ответа на предыдущий, вся патронная лента генерится заранее еще до стрельбы.

Если вам нужны сценарии с генерацией запросов "на лету", используйте [JMeter](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#jmeter) или [BFG](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#bfg).

Я не понял, какой вы пытаетесь использовать формат патронов. Если это [request style](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#request-style), то выглядеть лента должна как обычные HTTP запросы, записанные в файл последовательно с указанием размера каждого:

```
73 good
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx.tanks.example.com
Cookie: <authorization cookie>
User-Agent: xxx (shell 1)

77 bad
GET /abra HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx.tanks.example.com
Cookie: <authorization cookie>
User-Agent: xxx (shell 1)

78 unknown
GET /ab ra HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx.tanks.example.com
Cookie: <authorization cookie>
User-Agent: xxx (shell 1)
```